# google drive sdk - What are the JavaScript Origins and Authorized Redirect URLs?

Tags: google-drive-api

While creating the Client_ID I am stuck in these two textboxes (JavaScript Origins and Authorized Redirect URLs) appearing on that PopUp. I am not able to search the internet about those two things.

In a tutorial it was written that we just need to put our hostnames there! But why? What do they actually mean?

Hope I am clear.

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the JavaScript client, you need to set a valid JavaScript origin for us to authorize you.

Authorized redirect URIs are the endpoints we're going to call as a callback if you're using 3-legged OAuth 2.0 flow. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#webserver illustrates a sequence where Google endpoints pushes a code to your application. Push is done by calling a redirect url with a code query parameter.

```
http://yoursite/callback?code=[code to exchange]
```

Comment: it looks like if I specify different URLs for JavaScript Origins and Authorized Redirect URLs, I get the error:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964405/using-azure-mobile-app-for-google-authentication