# using Azure Mobile App for Google authentication

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-authentication, azure-mobile-services

I follow this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication/) for Google authentication for my web application.

I specified the following in my Google Developers Console:

```
Authorized JavaScript origins = my Azure mobile app url

Authorized redirect URIs = my web app url + /.auth/login/google/callback
```

[image]

But in this case I get the following error:

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> The redirect URI in the request:
>   mobile app url + .auth/login/google/callback did
>   not match a registered redirect URI.

[image]

If I use url of my mobile app instead of web app url for Authorized redirect URIs, it work, but not redirected to my web site.

How I can specify different urls for Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URIs?

Comment: For HTML/JS, you may also need to update the Mobile Apps / Web App allowed external URIs and update CORS.  Review the external redirect URIs topic here and see if it applies to you: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-how-to-use-client-library/#auth-getinfo

Comment: I added CORS in Azure; about external URIs, I think it's related to Cordova App, not web site. And anyway I'm getting the same error and this error from Google, so I think Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URI should be the same?

Comment: It depends on the specifics of your Cordova app - some frameworks (e.g. running in Ripple, Ionic Live Reload) provide a local loopback that you need to add.  I'm also hoping that the URL you provided was an actual URL.  Perhaps you can update the errors and settings to show actually what you entered but replace your site name with xxxx if you don't want it known.

Comment: Right now I'm trying to use Mobile App for web site authentication, I think I can do this. I have also Cordova App. but it's hosted. I added screenshots, I left names, it isn't secret.

Comment: other question: why do I need Azure Mobile App if I can use just use the following code for Google authentication: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

Comment: Azure Mobile Apps provides a scalable infrastructure for running your apps, staging environments, continuous deployment, push notifications, data access and offline sync capabilities.  Auth is just one feature.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely running into the External Redirect URIs based on your Hosted comment.  Check out the authentication section of the developer guide here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-how-to-use-client-library/#auth - the last section is on updating CORS and the external redirect URIs.

Comment: problem was that I just go to Authorized JavaScript origins url, it authenticate and forward to Authorized redirect URI automatically. In reality I need to use JavaScript client.login: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library/